# Creating a sink patch in Netlogo 6.0.4

Tags: netlogo, patch

I want to create 2 patches (or areas in the grid, not to be confused with regular Netlogo patches) in Netlogo that represent "sink" and "source" areas. The "sink" patch is a slider that can be adjusted in size, and should create a circular area. The "source" patch is the area outside of the sink patch. Below is the code I've used to try and implement this, it was taken from a similar model used in Netlogo 5.3.1:

```
to setup
clear-all

crt sink-patch-radius

;; create the 'sink'
set sk1x random-pxcor
set sk1y random-pycor
while [abs(sk1x - min-pxcor) < (sink-patch-radius - 1)
or abs(max-pxcor - sk1x) < (sink-patch-radius - 1)
or abs(sk1y - min-pycor) < (sink-patch-radius - 1)
or abs(max-pycor - sk1y) < (sink-patch-radius - 1) ]
[ set sk1y random-pycor
set sk1x random-pxcor ]


set sink-patches patches with
[(round(distancexy sk1x sk1y)) < sink-patch-radius ]
ask sink-patches [ set pcolor brown + 2 ]


;; create the 'source'
ask patches [
set source-patches patches with [pcolor != brown + 2]]
ask source-patches [ set pcolor green ]
```

When I do this, the setup button gets stuck. It will not set up the model. Strangely, this code seems to work in Netlogo 5.3.1. Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the setup button gets stuck. But there is a problem with your code. You have `ask patches [ set source-patches ...]` and that will get every patch to do it. That should be fairly fast but may explain your stickiness problem.

This amended version of your code works

```
to setup
  clear-all
  let sink-patch-radius 3
  crt sink-patch-radius

  ;; create the 'sink'
  let sk1x random-pxcor
  let sk1y random-pycor
  while [ abs(sk1x - min-pxcor) < (sink-patch-radius - 1)
          or abs(max-pxcor - sk1x) < (sink-patch-radius - 1)
          or abs(sk1y - min-pycor) < (sink-patch-radius - 1)
          or abs(max-pycor - sk1y) < (sink-patch-radius - 1) ]
  [ set sk1y random-pycor
    set sk1x random-pxcor ]
  let sink-patches patches with [(round(distancexy sk1x sk1y)) < sink-patch-radius ]
  ask sink-patches [ set pcolor brown + 2 ]

  ;; create the 'source'
  let source-patches patches with [pcolor != brown + 2]
  ask source-patches [ set pcolor green ]  
end
```

But I'm not sure why you are mucking around with a `while` statement instead of simply identifying the patches that are close. Try this for an easier to read version (note that there are no turtles so you would need to change it to bring that back in)

```
globals [ sink-patches source-patches]

to setup
  clear-all
  ;; create the 'sink'
  let sink-patch-radius 3
  let sink-centre one-of patches
  set sink-patches [patches in-radius sink-patch-radius] of sink-centre
  ask sink-patches [ set pcolor brown + 2 ]
  ;; create the 'source'
  set source-patches patches with [pcolor != brown + 2]
  ask source-patches [ set pcolor green ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I do have the sink-patches and source-patches as global variables because they are used elsewhere in the code. The simplified code you provided makes sense, the only issue is that the global variable "sink-patches" is never defined in that version, so I'm trying to think of how to incorporate it so that way it can be used elsewhere? But this was very helpful and it's working now.

Comment: see revised for globals version

Comment: Thanks so much! One last thing, do you mean to use "sink-patches" in the areas that say "let source-centre..." "ask source-patches [patches in-radius..] and "ask source-patches [set pcolor..]? I'm assuming you do, since that is where I'm creating the sink, not the source.

Comment: yes, I will fix. sorry, wasn't paying attention in my edits